# Basic resizing with paperclip/imagemagick not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm building a Rails 3.1 app and I'm using S3 and paperclip in a for photo storage, but I keep getting the following error:

```
RuntimeError (Style thumb has no processors defined.):
```

Here are the pertinent lines from my Photo model:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
:default_style => :original,
:styles => {:thumb => "150x150>"},
:url => "uploads/photos/:id/photo.:extension",
:path => "uploads/photos/:id/photo.:extension",
:storage => :s3
```

Here is the code around line 49 in the photos controller:

```
@photo = current_user.photos.new
@photo.caption = params['Filename']
# first save so that we can render a row
@photo.save
@photo.photo = params['Filedata']

Thread.new do 
  # second save to upload the photo
  @photo.save
end
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick and the `convert` tool installed in a place that Paperclip can find it?

Comment: which convert -> /usr/local/bin/convert, and I have Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/usr/local/bin/" in my development.rb environment file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was overriding the default settings class method for Paperclip in an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the paperclip documentation on processors, it seems to me that the default processor (Paperclip::Thumbnail) does not get attached. You could try and add it manually with:

```
:processors => [:thumbnail]
```

Comment: Well, that changed the error at least. Now it is: 

`You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]):
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:49:in 'create'`

Comment: Could you show us the code around line 49 in the PhotosController?

Comment: why are you doing this double saving, I have not seen this before. Has this to do with the S3 storage? Wouldn't it suffice to simply say `@photo = current_user.create_photo(params[:photo])` and `@photo.save`?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. It has to do with s3 storage, yes. I need to have an id for the image when the method returns, but I don't want to wait for the photo to be uploaded to s3.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OSX users:

installing [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and running

```
brew install imagemagick
```

did the trick for me.

PS. If the installation of imagemagick results in something like this:

> Error: The linking step did not complete successfully
> The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local

run:

```
sudo brew link imagemagick
```